# counting sub rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have 2 table ok `catgories` and `artilces`
i have this structure
catgories

```
web > design > photoshop > layers
web > design > photoshop > effects
```

and each one is a catgory
and layers catgories has `100` article
and effects catgories has `50` article

now i want when count the articles 'web' catgory it show 150 article
how i can do this
give me an example

Comment: Are you storing your categories in some recursive way or is this just text? Is your table really called `artilces`?

Answer (score -1):

```
select category,count(*)
group by category
```